# Database, Table, Authorization and Authentication Question

Tags: database, sveltekit, supabase

I'm new to database type things and I should add I'm a self taught programmer just trying to learn. I'm building an app with sveltekit and supabase and I just had a few design questions about how I should go about making this. This isn't a coding question and I'll trying to word it the best I can. Also I'm not really sure how to search for my question and trust me I tried that first.

In my app I plan on making the user able to start a company profile and the company data with be shared among employees who will have different privilege's.

My question is, in the database when you make a table, say a simple contact table that will be shared among the employees, is it correct to have just one table in the database that uses unique id's (like a company and employee id) to query the data or is it correct that unique "contact" tables would be created for each company?

I guess to sum up my what I'm trying to ask, would one "contact" table hold all the contacts for all the companies using that app or would is be better to create a contact template and then each company would have their own "contact" table to query?

I imagine if you have hundreds of companies each with possibly hundred of contacts, querying the data could take a long time but I don't really know. Like I said this is a design question and I hope it makes sense. Its hard to put into words and harder to search but any advice would be helpful.

Thank you.

I tried searching for answers and couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One table for one type of data. There are ways to managing query performance, primarily indexes on the columns that will be used to query the data. Some databases also have ways of completely segmenting the table internally, but it can still be used like a single table.

In this scenario you will probably want three tables: Companies, users and a third one associating users with a company.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have read that its typical to make 3 tables. In the third table, is that where you would store user permissions and authentication? Once again, thank you!

Comment: Probably not, unless those are different per-company. Authentication usually happens at the application level. The table is just for association, you can actually drop it, if you know that each user can only ever belong to one company; in that case you can add a column to the user that references the company directly.